# Trying to understand implication

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm currently slogging through propositional calculus and making my brain do impressions of a pretzel, but I'm slowly getting it though I'd like to see if that's actually true for the problem below. Is my answer correct for the below proposition?:

(p $\rightarrow$ p) $\lor$ (q $\rightarrow$ q) $\rightarrow$ p $\lor$ q

My p and q truth table is oriented with 0 and 0, and at the bottom is 1 and 1. My final result came to:

> (p $\rightarrow$ p) $\lor$ (q $\rightarrow$ q) $\rightarrow$ p $\lor$ q
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1

Sorry for the awful formatting, but I'm having trouble trying to whip up a truth table on this. Hopefully you get the idea? In

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table for $$[(p \implies p) \lor (q \implies q)]\implies (p \lor q)$$
is equivalent to proposition: $\;p\lor q$, which has precisely the same truth-table assignment as does your statement.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

Both of the Or'ed statements $(p \implies p),\;(q \implies q)$ are tautologies (true regardless of the truth values of p, and of q), and so also is, the disjunction $$(p \implies p) \lor (q \implies q)$$ It is true no matter what the truth values of $p$ and $q$. So the only way your statement can be false is if the consequence of the main implication is false: the consequence of the *main* implication is the disjunction $(p\lor q).\;$ And $\;p \lor q\;$ is false if and only if  $p$ is false and $q$ is false.

Comment: I'm glad this stuff seems to be sinking it, bit by bit. Checking this as the answer due to the inclusion of a truth table.

Comment: I'm glad it's all sinking in, Harry! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Such a nicely formatted and color coded table! +1 Oh, it is an image - do you use some program and create that?

Answer (score 3):

The left side is always true. So the whole thing is true except when $p$ and $q$ are both false. If your truth table says that, fine.

For $p$ true, $q$ true, result is true.

For $p$ true, $q$ false, result is true.

For $p$ false, $q$ true, result is true.

For $p$ false, $q$ false, result is false.

Thus the sentence is equivalent ot $p\lor q$.

Comment: Success, then! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A different perspective, less helpful in context:

$p \implies p$ is true by the law of identity.

Thus $(p\implies p)\lor(q\implies q)$ is true by the law of addition.

Thus the proposition you are considering can be simplified to $\top \implies p \lor q$.

If $\top\implies p\lor q$, then $p\lor q$ is true by modus ponens.

If $p \lor q$ is true, then since every proposition implies a true statement, $\top \implies p\lor q$.

Thus your proposition is equivalent to $p \lor q$.